# onchange trigger for an unordered list

Tags: javascript, google-chrome-extension

I am programming my frist Chrome Extension being beginner at Javascript and I have the next problem: 
I want to select the hashtag area of Twitter, which is an ul with li inside, waiting for a new li to be added to call a function. I don't know how to do a trigger because neither of these have worked:

```js
//The <ul> from hashtag area:
var tl = document.getElementsByClassName('trend-items')[0];

//1.
tl.onchange = function(){
  doMyThings();
}

//2.
tl.addEventListener("change", function(){
  doMyThings();
});
```

Moreover, when I change the screen without exiting Twitter (I mean, getting into a profile for example), my code doesn't execute.

Thanks!

Comment: There is no `onchange` event associated with `ul` tags.

Comment: Check into the `MutationObserver`: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/MutationObserver

Comment: I would post the HTML with this for context. As @Kevin stated, there is not onchange event associated with an li. You may try the click event instead.

Comment: First of all, thank you for answering. I know onchange does not work with ul tags, I'm looking for another valid option. I'm testing MutationObserver and it seems very useful.
About HTML, the ul I am focusing is this one:
`<ul class="trend-items js-trends">
    <li>...
    <li>...
</ul>`

Answer (score 0):

`UL` have no change event, but you can achieve it by `MutationObserver` like following way. Insert or delete any `li` item from inside `.trend-items` you will see that every time `doMyThings` function will trigger.

```
<ul class="trend-items">
    <li>item one1</li>
    <li>item one2</li>
</ul>

var tl = document.getElementsByClassName('trend-items')[0];

var config = { childList: true };

var doMyThings = function(mutationsList) {
    console.log('UL item inseted/deleted');
};

var observer = new MutationObserver(doMyThings);

observer.observe(tl, config);
```

Comment: Thank you for answering! I've tried that solution but it is not working for me. When hashtags are loaded dynamically it show nothing on console.log.

Comment: You can do anything inside doMyThings() function. You wrote " I don't know how to do a trigger" so I showed you how can you trigger when li inside ul insert or remove.